# how to find the layout width and height in xml?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

[image]

In this image as show red box ,in that i'm displaying a `ListView`

How to display the list view and how to find the width and height of the image??

In this red box i'm displaying a `ListView` (like contacts), but i'm adding a list view in
  run time.

How to find the that red box size in run time??

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/cm"
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/backbg"
  >


   <LinearLayout 
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
  >


<AbsoluteLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"


  >

  <Button 
       android:id="@+id/ckbtn0"
       android:layout_width="54dp"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:background="@drawable/back1"

       android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
       android:layout_x="-1dp"
       android:layout_y="5dp"
    /> 



      <Button 
       android:id="@+id/refresh0"
        android:layout_width="54dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:layout_x="74dp"
       android:layout_y="5dp" 
       android:background="@drawable/refresh1"
      /> 
      <Button
    android:id="@+id/ImageView01" 
     android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:background="@drawable/search1"
    android:layout_x="230dp" 
    android:layout_y="5dp">
    </Button>
              <EditText 
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/cet0"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility = "gone"
            android:layout_x="297dp"
            android:layout_y="15dp" 
            android:singleLine="true" 
            android:imeActionLabel="Search"
            />


     <Button 
        android:id="@+id/ckbtn1"
        android:layout_width="54dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/add"
        android:layout_x="429dp"
        android:layout_y="5dp" 
         /> 


    </AbsoluteLayout>

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="309dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
         />            






      <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="490dp"
      android:gravity="top"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
      >

   <ListView android:id="@+id/clistview"  
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:divider="#2867EA"
   android:dividerHeight="1dp"


    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    >
  </ListView>
  </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout 
   android:orientation="horizontal" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent"
  android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
  >


   <Button android:id="@+id/pbtn0"
    android:layout_width="76dp"
android:layout_height="35dp"
   android:layout_gravity="bottom"
  android:background="@null"
    android:layout_x="-1dp"
android:layout_y="393dp"

    />


     <Button android:id="@+id/nbtn1"
      android:layout_width="53dp"
  android:layout_height="33dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
     android:background="@null"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
     android:layout_x="300dp"
android:layout_y="450dp" 

    />

    </LinearLayout>




    </LinearLayout>   

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Pleas clarify what are you doing when what you want to do, if needed show some code.

Comment: plz see this.................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your layout is a little bit messy , it would better we fix that frist, but to display your listView do something like this:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.clistview); 
listView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

Take a look in the [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html)

another advice don't devine   the width and the height  manually, because you don't know the size of the device, better use the fill_parent, wrap_content, or use the weigth to control it.

I made some changes in your layout, take a look and put your images in the components:

code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ckbtn0"
        android:layout_width="54dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/refresh0"
        android:layout_width="54dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp" >
    </Button>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/cet0"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ckbtn1"
        android:layout_width="54dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_y="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:text="TextView" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/clistview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pbtn0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nbtn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: sir i'm trying to get the red box  width and height to display the contacts in that. plz tell me how to find the width and height .